# How to override Hadoop dependency in Oozie workflow?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I need to use a newer version of jsch than is currently bundled with hadoop-common.

When I run my job with `hadoop jar` I use `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=path/to/jsch-0.1.51.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true` and it works fine.

But I could not make it work in an Oozie workflow. I put jsch-0.1.51.jar in the lib directory of my Oozie workflow workspace but it is loaded last in the classpath. I also tried `oozie.libpath` but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>foo.bar.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.jcraft.jsch</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.jcraft.jsch</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```